# Persistence for a menu of levels with sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, menu, sprite-kit, persistence

I'm trying to make a menu with different levels, with the game having only three open levels to start with.

The problem is saving lead levels.

I have managed to make the levels show their respective number if they are open and a padlock if they are not. When you finish the previous level a new level opens.

I would like this to save so that when you close the app, the level progress is not eliminated.

I tried using .plist but they don't let me use numbers as the variable name in the plist, so it's difficult to take the information respective to each level. I show you.

My .plist it´s a matrix of dictionary, who inside has other dictionaries compuse with three components (finish level,level,openclosed):

```
<dict>
 <key>Diez5</key>
 <dict>
    <key>finishEnd</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>level</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
    <key>openClosed</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
 </dict>
 <key>Once5</key>
 <dict>
    <key>finishEnd</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>level</key>
    <integer>11</integer>
    <key>openClosed</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
 </dict>
 <key>Uno</key>
 <dict>
    <key>finishEnd</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>level</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>openClosed</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
 </dict> 
 ...
 ...</dict>
```

Next I have the class who work with this:

```
 class MenuList {

 var matriz4 = [["Ocho","Nueve","Diez","Once"], ["Cuatro","Cinco","Seis","Siete"], ["Matriz","Uno","Dos","Tres"]]

 var matriz5 = [["Ocho5","Nueve5","Diez5","Once5"], ["Cuatro5","Cinco5","Seis5","Siete5"], ["Matriz5","Uno5","Dos5","Tres5"]]

 let levelKey = "level"
 let openClosedKey = "openClosed"
 let finishKey = "finishEnd"

 let columnNum: Int!
 let rowNum: Int!

 let plist = Plist(name: "MatrizMenu")

 var levelID: Int!
 var openCID: Int!
 var finishID: Int!

 init() {

    self.columnNum = matriz4.count + 1
    self.rowNum = matriz4.count
 }

 func getTile(column: Int, row: Int, matrixNum: Int) -> (SKSpriteNode,SKLabelNode) {

    let textLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "HelveticaRoundedLTStd-BdCn")
    textLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textLabel.text = " "

    switch(matrixNum){
    case 4:

        let dict = plist?.getMutablePlistFile()!
        if let myDict = dict![matriz4[row][column]] {

            openCID = myDict.valueForKey(openClosedKey) as! Int!
            finishID = myDict.valueForKey(finishKey) as! Int!

            if matriz4[row][column] == "Matriz" {

                textLabel.text = "4x4"
                return (SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rectangle-play"),textLabel)

            } else if openCID != 0 && finishID == 0 {
                levelID = myDict.valueForKey(levelKey) as! Int!
                textLabel.text = "\(levelID)"
                return (SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "UnfinishTile"), textLabel)

            } else if openCID != 0 && finishID != 0 {
                levelID = myDict.valueForKey(levelKey) as! Int!
                textLabel.text = "\(levelID)"
                return (SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "FinishTile"), textLabel)

            }else {
                textLabel.text = "lock"
                return (SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rectangle-play-normal"), textLabel)
            }
        }

    case 5:

        let dict = plist?.getMutablePlistFile()!
        if let myDict = dict![matriz5[row][column]] {

            openCID = myDict.valueForKey(openClosedKey) as! Int!

            if matriz5[row][column] == "Matriz5" {

                let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor(red: 1, green: 0.541, blue: 0.298, alpha: 1), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
                textLabel.text = "5x5"
                return (sprite,textLabel)

            } else if openCID != 0 && finishID == 0 {
                levelID = myDict.valueForKey(levelKey) as! Int!
                textLabel.text = "\(levelID)"
                return (SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "UnfinishTile"), textLabel)


            } else if openCID != 0 && finishID != 0 {
                levelID = myDict.valueForKey(levelKey) as! Int!
                textLabel.text = "\(levelID)"
                return (SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "FinishTile"), textLabel)

            }else {
                textLabel.text = "lock"
                return (SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rectangle-play-normal"),  textLabel)
            }

        }

    default:
        return (SKSpriteNode(), textLabel)

    }

    return (SKSpriteNode(), textLabel)
 }

 func get_level(column: Int, row: Int, matrixNum: Int) -> (Int,Bool) {

    switch(matrixNum){
    case 4:

        let dict = plist?.getMutablePlistFile()!
        if let myDict = dict!["\(matriz4[row][column])"] {

            openCID = myDict.valueForKey(openClosedKey) as! Int!
            levelID = myDict.valueForKey(levelKey) as! Int!

            if matriz4[row][column] != "Matriz" && openCID != 0 {
                return (levelID,true)
            }
        }
        break

    case 5:

        let dict = plist?.getMutablePlistFile()!
        if let myDict = dict!["\(matriz5[row][column])"] {

            openCID = myDict.valueForKey(openClosedKey) as! Int!
            levelID = myDict.valueForKey(levelKey) as! Int

            if matriz5[row][column] != "Matriz5" && openCID != 0 {
                return (levelID,true)
            }
        }
        break

    default:
        return (0,false)
    }
    return (0,false)
 }

 func getBool(column: Int, row: Int) -> Bool {

    if matriz4[row][column] == "Matriz" {
        return true
    } else { return false }
 }

}
```

And this is the plist class I find to work ([Help for plist](http://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/#comment-45)):

```
import CoreData

struct Plist {
 //1
 enum PlistError: ErrorType {
    case FileNotWritten
    case FileDoesNotExist
}
//2
let name:String
//3
var sourcePath:String? {
    guard

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: "plist")

        else { return .None }
    return path
}
//4
var destPath:String? {
    guard sourcePath != .None else { return .None }
    let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    return (dir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(name).plist")
}

init?(name:String) {
    //1
    self.name = name
    //2
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    //3
    guard let source = sourcePath else { return nil }
    guard let destination = destPath else { return nil }
    guard fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(source) else { return nil }
    //4
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destination) {
        //5
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(source, toPath: destination)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Unable to copy file. ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}

//1
func getValuesInPlistFile() -> NSDictionary?{
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destPath!) {
        guard let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: destPath!) else { return .None }
        return dict
    } else {
        return .None
    }
}
//2
func getMutablePlistFile() -> NSMutableDictionary?{
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destPath!) {
        guard let dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: destPath!) else { return .None }
        return dict
    } else {
        return .None
    }
}
//3
func addValuesToPlistFile(dictionary:NSDictionary) throws {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destPath!) {
        if !dictionary.writeToFile(destPath!, atomically: false) {
            print("File not written successfully")
            throw PlistError.FileNotWritten
        }
    } else {
        throw PlistError.FileDoesNotExist
    }
}
```

}

So, How can I save the level progress?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: PList should work fine,  can you explain how you are laying out your plist

Comment: Thats what I do with the plist the problem its the name I put, It´s very difficult work without number because I will  a func that receive the number and return the number on word (1 -> One), but the plist don't let me put number :(   @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Hmm your code looks more complicated then it needs to be, NSDictionary has functions built in to write and read from plists (`dict.writeToFile(...)` and `dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:)`). Then if you want it as a Swift dictionary, just cast it `let swiftDict = dict as! [NSObject:AnyObject]`

Answer (score 1):

There is a few ways to do this. I am currently finishing my game where I am having similar menu using a UICollectionView. To store the data I created an array of dictionaries for this in my Singleton game data class that handles game saving.

For example

```
var unlockedLevels: [[String: Bool]] = [
    // Empty, so array starts at index 1 and not 0
    [:],
    // World 1
    ["1": true, "2": false, "3": false, "4": false], // Level 1-4
    // World 2
    ...
]
```

I than use the indexPath in my collection view to check which cell is pressed and compare that to the array to see if it is unlocked and load the level.

```
    let world = indexPath.section + 1 // + 1 because indexPath starts at 0
    let level = indexPath.row + 1 // If collection view is horizontal need to convert this because indexPath goes up/down not left/right.

    // Load level only if unlocked, otherwise exit method
    guard GameData.sharedInstance.unlockedLevels[world]["\(level)"] == true else { return }

   // code to load level
```

You than just make sure to change the cells depending if the level is unlocked or not. I do it this way in my CellForRowAtIndexPath method of my collection view, which has 2 cells, 1 normal, 1 locked. 
I could not get it to work reliable with 1 cell because of cell dequeuing and reuse.

```
    let world = indexPath.section + 1
    let level = indexPath.row + 1

    if GameData.sharedInstance.unlockedLevels[world]["\(level)"] == true {
        return cell // returns normal cell to play level
    } else {
        return cellLocked // returns cell with padlock.
    }
```

Than once a level is completed you set the bool for the corresponding level to true and save the progress.

To save the array you can use NSCoding, NSUserDefaults or for the best solution Keychain.

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/12/3/fixing-project-10-nscoding

[how to don't get a nil value from NSUserDefaults in ViewDidLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880173/how-to-dont-get-a-nil-value-from-nsuserdefaults-in-viewdidload/35898073#35898073)

https://github.com/jrendel/SwiftKeychainWrapper

https://www.raywenderlich.com/63235/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-1-of-2    (Obj C but I think still useful)

Not 100% sure this is what you are looking for because I dont use Plists. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the information, its really helpful but the problem is them I have a matrix not an array, and when I try to save a matrix with NUserDefaults or NScoding doesn't work :(  If you know the way to do it with a matrix I will more grateful then know. Thank you to much!

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by matrix. Could you post some code which helps people understand your problem better.

Comment: I put the code I make using plist. I hope you understand

Comment: Sorry man, not sure how to help. I have to say tho this looks way more complicated than my way. I think KnighOfDragon might be better suited for your question.

Comment: Matrix should just be a 2D array

Comment: I have never used one before, I understand what a 2d array is but its properly better for someone else with more knowledge about them to help.

Comment: Don´t worry I understand. I will try your way. I trying to fine other way to do it. Thank you very much! @crashoverride777